# How to access Map control from plugins in the DemoMap DotSpatial program

Tags: dotspatial

I am using the `DotSpatial DemoMap` as the main frontend in my application, and I created a number of plugins to be loaded into DemoMap at launch and they are working. However, I am not very clear how to allow my custom plugins to access the main map control.

I see in the main form of DemoMap, there is `App.Map` property as the handle to the main map control (am I right?), if this is true, then I suppose I need to pass it into each plugin when it is initiated?

Bottom line, what is the most efficient/best way to allow the main map control to be accessible throughout the entire application from all custom plugins? (I am using DotSpatial 2.0 libraries on .Net 4.5.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive from `Extension` and access the `AppManger`-supplied map via the `App.Map` property.

An extension (plugin) can access the map via the `App.Map` property. The is accessible to any class which derives from `Extension` so it doesn't need to be passed into the plugin.
The AppManager which lets you access that property is injected via MEF automatically.

Here's a sample extension

```
public class SimpleMapPlugin : Extension
{
    public SimpleMapPlugin()
    {
        // Access App.Map as needed.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I imagined as well, I will mark this as the answer, but I would like to add that for non-extension support libraries, one would have to pass the App into it for access.